# Integrate a picture with Tkinter

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, tkinter

I am a begginner in Python. I'm trying to display a picture with Tkinter in a window, but I don't success...

This is a piece of my code :

```
import serial
import time
import sys
import os

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("500x500")

[...]

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the Frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        [...]

        try:
            self.photo=PhotoImage('buttongreen.gif') 
            pic = Canvas(self,width =256, height = 256, bg ='blue')
            pic.grid(row=6, columnspan=2,column=0,padx = 10, pady =10)
            pic.create_image(256,256, image=self.photo)
            """self.panel = Label(self, image = photo)
            self.panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")"""
        except:
            print "Unable to load image"
[...]

app = Application(root)
app.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the canvas is displaying only the background, not the picture, can you tell me what is wrong please?

Note : The buttongreen.gif is in the same folder that my .py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.photo=PhotoImage('buttongreen.gif')
```

Should be...

```
self.photo=PhotoImage(file = 'buttongreen.gif')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `file=` in `self.photo = PhotoImage(file='buttongreen.gif')`

Working example

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry("500x500")

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the Frame"""
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.grid()

    def create_widgets(self):

        try:
            self.photo = PhotoImage(file='buttongreen.gif') # file =

            pic = Canvas(self, width=256, height=256, bg='blue')
            pic.grid(row=6, columnspan=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

            pic.create_image(256, 256, image=self.photo)

        except:
            print "Unable to load image"

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```